# Transform eloquent model using fractal

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, transformer-model

I am trying to use [fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/) to convert dates in my [eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent) model when sending it to a web page via ajax. However, I'm not getting the expected transformed data object. Here's my code:

Transformer:

```
<?php

namespace App\Transformers\Models;

use App\Models\Student;
use League\Fractal;

class StudentTransformer extends Fractal\TransformerAbstract
{
    public function transform(Student $student)
    {
        return [
            'name'           => $student->name,
            'birth_date'     => date('d-m-Y', strtotime($student->birth_date)),
            'start_date'     => date('d-m-Y', strtotime($student->start_date)),
            'is_active'      => $student->is_active ? 'Yes' : 'No',
            'course_title'   => $student->course_title,
            'university_id'  => $student->university_id,
            'institution_id' => $student->institution_id,
            'course_id'      => $student->course_id,
        ];
    }
}
```

Routes file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    $student = App\Models\Student::first();

    $response = new League\Fractal\Resource\Item($student, new App\Transformers\Models\StudentTransformer);

    return response()->json([$response]);

});
```

returns this:

```
[
    { }
]
```

if I `dd()`, like so:

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    $student = App\Models\Student::first();

    $response = new League\Fractal\Resource\Item($student, new App\Transformers\Models\StudentTransformer);

    dd($response);

});
```

I get the following, with no apparent transformations made

```
Item {#299 ▼
  #data: Student {#305 ▼
    #fillable: array:10 [▼
      0 => "name"
      1 => "birth_date"
      2 => "start_date"
      3 => "is_active"
      4 => "course_title"
      5 => "university_id"
      6 => "institution_id"
      7 => "course_id"
    ]
    #connection: null
    #table: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #perPage: 15
    +incrementing: true
    +timestamps: true
    #attributes: array:13 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "name" => "Michel Jast"
      "birth_date" => "1979-12-22"
      "start_date" => "2015-08-02"
      "is_active" => 1
      "course_title" => "quia"
      "university_id" => "10954"
      "institution_id" => 1044
      "course_id" => 1
      "created_at" => "2015-11-23 09:40:35"
      "updated_at" => "2015-11-26 10:24:14"
    ]
    #original: array:13 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "name" => "Michel Jast"
      "birth_date" => "1979-12-22"
      "start_date" => "2015-08-02"
      "is_active" => 1
      "course_title" => "quia"
      "university_id" => "10954"
      "institution_id" => 1044
      "course_id" => 1
      "created_at" => "2015-11-23 09:40:35"
      "updated_at" => "2015-11-26 10:24:14"
    ]
    #relations: []
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #appends: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #casts: []
    #touches: []
    #observables: []
    #with: []
    #morphClass: null
    +exists: true
  }
  #meta: []
  #resourceKey: null
  #transformer: StudentTransformer {#301 ▼
    #availableIncludes: []
    #defaultIncludes: []
    #currentScope: null
  }
}
```

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My implementation is the following :

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    $student = App\Models\Student::first();

    $response = new League\Fractal\Resource\Item($student, new App\Transformers\Models\StudentTransformer);

    $manager = new \League\Fractal\Manager();
    $manager->setSerializer(new \League\Fractal\Serializer\ArraySerializer());

    return response()->json($manager->createData($response)->toArray());

});
```

You have to create a `\League\Fractal\Manager` instance and assign a serializer into it. The manager will return the data into array or others.

In [fractal page](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/serializers/), there is more detail.

Comment: Seems to work just great! Thank you @YMHuang. I will be sure to check out the link on the `Manager`, clearly I was missing something! Now I need how to figure out transformations for related models lol! Once again thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Ive not used Factral in a project but I think you need to do something like.

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    $student = App\Models\Student::first();

    $response = new League\Fractal\Resource\Item($student, new App\Transformers\Models\StudentTransformer);

    return response()->json($response->toArray());

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Lee - I'm afraid it doesn't work. I get the following: `Call to undefined method League\Fractal\Resource\Item::toArray()`